# OpenVPN not pushing remote gateway

Tags: openvpn

I have a problem with OpenVPN. I've successfully managed to setup an OpenVPN server on my router which is running TomatoUSB.

I then followed the following steps on 1 client computer.

1. Download the latest version of OpenVPN with OpenVPN GUI
2. Copy the certs and config files into the config directory
3. Connect

On the client I tested the remote-gateway was being pushed correctly. In other words on this client computer I was able to route all internet traffic through the vpn, public IP address changed to reflect this - awesome!

Job done I thought, so I got a friend involved to test the vpn from China. He followed the exact same steps - He's running a 32bit version of Win7. I was running a 64bit version, besides that he took the same steps to setup his client.

He can connect, however his public IP remains the same, and his internet traffic is not routed through the vpn.

I have no idea what to do from here, but I am pretty sure the server is correctly configured, because at least 1 client gets full routing.

So I am wondering could this have anything to do with him being in China? Or is there some setting I don't know about?

How to solve this?

Comment: Wow that is interesting - post an OpenVPN question on serverfault, someone downvotes it and attempts to close the question for being offtopic. Exactly how is this not a server related question?

Comment: It's more that all the tech you've mentioned in your post isn't "professional" IT. So, it's likely your post may find a better home in a different site, like superuser.com.

Comment: Post configs used...  Post route table after connected.  Post logs.  Give us something to work with...

Answer (score 0):

For your friend running Win7, is he running OpenVPN as an administrator?  The GUI needs admin rights in order to be able to change the routing table.